# Expected value of keys which have different color from 2 other keys around it in a key holder colored by 2 colors

Tags: probability, expected-value

There is a key holder containing n keys. We color each key with blue or green. Then we bring up all keys that are of different color from 2 keys before and after it.

Now I want to find the expected value for keys with are brought up.

I did some practice on this problem. First I try to find the probability of each permutation in which k keys must be bro got up. All possible ways to color the keys is given by 2^n (each key can be blue or green).Now I know should find all ways of coloring keys that k keys have different color from their neighbors. But I couldn't do this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hint: Linearity of expectation.

Comment: More hint please. I couldn't solve.

Comment: What is the expected value that the first key is of a different color? What about the second key?

Comment: Does the key holder hold keys in a row or a circle ?